# Suspend not working - help needed to debug

Tags: suspend, dell, 17.04, acpi, wpa-supplicant

Since the past couple of days, each time I try to suspend my system, my laptop immediately resumes from suspend. I'm not sure what the exact error is.

I also noticed, that since this problem began, there's been no messages logged to `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`

Also, I cannot really decipher the syslog and figure out what the issue is.
I've copied in the relevant portions of my syslog below (atleast what I thought was relevant. If there is something else that I should add to the syslog dump, or any other log files that I need to add to the post, please let me know).

```
Dec 19 19:43:42 rocket systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Dec 19 19:43:42 rocket systemd-sleep[14238]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
Dec 19 19:43:42 rocket systemd-sleep[14245]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
Dec 19 19:43:42 rocket systemd-sleep[14238]: Suspending system...
Dec 19 19:43:42 rocket kernel: [97753.657438] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97753.657440] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97753.677370] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97753.679487] OOM killer disabled.
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97753.679487] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97753.681041] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97753.694559] e1000e: EEE TX LPI TIMER: 00000011
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.015324] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.058898] ACPI: EC: event blocked
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.058899] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.058901] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.059053] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.075214] irq_migrate_all_off_this_cpu: 1 callbacks suppressed
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.075217] IRQ 127: no longer affine to CPU1
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.076265] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.099125] IRQ 122: no longer affine to CPU2
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.099135] IRQ 123: no longer affine to CPU2
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.099152] IRQ 129: no longer affine to CPU2
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.099161] IRQ 133: no longer affine to CPU2
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.101239] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.127042] IRQ 1: no longer affine to CPU3
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.127053] IRQ 8: no longer affine to CPU3
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.127061] IRQ 9: no longer affine to CPU3
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.127070] IRQ 12: no longer affine to CPU3
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.127092] IRQ 124: no longer affine to CPU3
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.128146] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.134445] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.134553] ACPI: EC: EC started
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.134554] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.136858] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.136960] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.136961] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.138995]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.139198] CPU1 is up
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.139220] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.140866]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.141062] CPU2 is up
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.141089] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.142607]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.142810] CPU3 is up
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.145878] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97754.840298] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97755.373360] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97755.373390] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97755.394993] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97755.563924] restoring control 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000101/10/5
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97755.563928] restoring control 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000101/12/11
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97755.670949] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 37 using xhci_hcd
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97756.115174] usb 1-4.1: reset full-speed USB device number 38 using xhci_hcd
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97756.295223] usb 1-4.2: reset full-speed USB device number 39 using xhci_hcd
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97756.471198] OOM killer enabled.
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket systemd[3214]: Time has been changed
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97756.471201] Restarting tasks ... 
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97756.477635] [drm] RC6 on
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97756.479382] done.
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97756.509711] acpi PNP0401:00: Already enumerated
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket compiz[3686]: WARN  2017-12-19 19:43:49 unity.glib.dbus.proxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:487 Calling method "EmitEvent" on object path: "/com/ubuntu/Upstart" failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.canonical.Unity.Test.Upstart was not provided by any .service files
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket systemd[1]: Reloading Laptop Mode Tools.
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97756.599394] acpi PNP0501:00: Still not present
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket laptop_mode[14272]: Laptop mode
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket laptop_mode[14272]: enabled, not active [unchanged]
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket systemd-sleep[14238]: System resumed.
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket kernel: [97756.656991] PM: suspend exit
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket systemd-sleep[14238]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket systemd-sleep[14317]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket systemd[1]: Started Suspend.
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket systemd[1]: sleep.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket systemd[1]: suspend.target: Unit is bound to inactive unit systemd-suspend.service. Stopping, too.
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Dec 19 19:43:49 rocket systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs at resume.
```

How do I fix this issue/debug this problem further?

I'm using 17.04 on a Dell Latitude E7470.

*PS: please leave a comment if there is any more information that I need to add to this question.*

Comment: if you google "ACPI: EC: EC started" you can find for example https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/suspend-wakes-right-back-up-4175581236/

Comment: @Valentas do you know how I can make this setting `echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup` persist from one reboot to the next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [Valentas](https://askubuntu.com/users/244383/valentas) for the linuxquestions link in your [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987755/suspend-not-working-help-needed-to-debug#comment1591260_987755)

I followed the thread in the above link and understood that the issue was related to connected USB 3.0 devices connected to my laptop.

the following command fixed the issue for me. Needs to be run as `root`

```
echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

The command does seem like you're writing to a file, but the effect that it has is to toggle USB devices from waking up the system.

If you're not sure that it's the USB that's waking up your system, check the run the following.

```
grep enabled /proc/acpi/wakeup | cut -f 1
```

If one of the output lines is `XHC` then that means that a USB device could be the issue. To test if this is the case, try suspend with the USB device disconnected. If you're machine doesn't automatically wake up from suspend, then it's probably a USB related.

Comment: For me at least, the toggle for `XHC` persists between suspends. There have been reports here/other forums of the toggle to `/proc/acpi/wakeup` resetting itself after each suspend-wake cycle.

Comment: I haven't tested if the toggle to `/proc/acpi/suspend` persists between reboots. If it doesn't, I'll try and find a solution and update the answer. If anyone else knows that it does/doesn't persist from one boot to the next, please comment/edit the answer.