# Ubuntu wakes up immediately after suspend, no usb attached

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, thinkpad

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a newly bought Thinkpad p53s; but every time I suspend the PC, it will suspend for one second and then immediately wake up.

I have tried multiple methods mentioned in various posts, e.g. [link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797590/ubuntu-wakes-up-immediately-after-suspend), [link2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148481/how-do-i-prevent-immediate-wake-up-from-suspend-and-or-hibernation), [link3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987755/suspend-not-working-help-needed-to-debug). None of those solved my problem.

1) nothing is attached to its USB ports

2) Bluetooth is turned off

3) The nouveau driver is installed

4) Everything in /proc/acpi/wakeup is disabled.

It still wakes up immediately after going into suspend mode.

Here are the relevant log file from dmesg:

```
[  987.097609] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp0s20f3: link becomes ready
[ 1468.175507] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 94:10:3e:e4:01:96 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 1469.577006] PM: suspend entry (deep)
[ 1469.577010] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[ 1470.617407] rfkill: input handler enabled
[ 1470.662087] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[ 1470.664302] OOM killer disabled.
[ 1470.664303] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 1470.665927] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[ 1470.944969] e1000e: EEE TX LPI TIMER: 00000011
[ 1471.313851] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[ 1471.393130] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[ 1471.400448] ACPI: EC: event blocked
[ 1471.400448] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
[ 1471.400448] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[ 1471.400467] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 1471.401716] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[ 1471.402159] irq_migrate_all_off_this_cpu: 8 callbacks suppressed
[ 1471.402160] IRQ 157: no longer affine to CPU2
[ 1471.403176] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[ 1471.404854] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[ 1471.405369] IRQ 167: no longer affine to CPU4
[ 1471.406367] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
[ 1471.406981] IRQ 16: no longer affine to CPU5
[ 1471.406985] IRQ 126: no longer affine to CPU5
[ 1471.408003] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
[ 1471.408389] IRQ 127: no longer affine to CPU6
[ 1471.408392] IRQ 128: no longer affine to CPU6
[ 1471.409399] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
[ 1471.409803] IRQ 122: no longer affine to CPU7
[ 1471.409806] IRQ 124: no longer affine to CPU7
[ 1471.409813] IRQ 158: no longer affine to CPU7
[ 1471.409815] IRQ 159: no longer affine to CPU7
[ 1471.410830] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
[ 1471.415220] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[ 1471.415321] ACPI: EC: EC started
[ 1471.415321] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[ 1471.416459] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 1471.416551] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[ 1471.416553] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[ 1471.417308]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[ 1471.417542] CPU1 is up
[ 1471.417560] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
[ 1471.417953]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[ 1471.418095] CPU2 is up
[ 1471.418110] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
[ 1471.418505]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[ 1471.418656] CPU3 is up
[ 1471.418671] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x1
[ 1471.419145]  cache: parent cpu4 should not be sleeping
[ 1471.419380] CPU4 is up
[ 1471.419398] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x3
[ 1471.419789]  cache: parent cpu5 should not be sleeping
[ 1471.419947] CPU5 is up
[ 1471.419962] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x5
[ 1471.420354]  cache: parent cpu6 should not be sleeping
[ 1471.420524] CPU6 is up
[ 1471.420539] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
[ 1471.420938]  cache: parent cpu7 should not be sleeping
[ 1471.421132] CPU7 is up
[ 1471.427249] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[ 1471.517272] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[ 1471.578626] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[ 1471.578800] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[ 1471.825299] usb 1-6: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 1471.906714] nvme nvme0: 8/0/0 default/read/poll queues
[ 1472.101638] usb 1-10: reset full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 1472.377603] usb 1-8: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 1472.506767] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5678], y [..4694]
[ 1472.541412] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1266..], y [1162..]
[ 1472.655073] usb 1-9: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 1472.815039] acpi LNXPOWER:08: Turning OFF
[ 1472.816988] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.1 build 42 week 52 2015
[ 1472.818162] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 2
[ 1472.818164] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[ 1472.818166] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[ 1472.818167] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[ 1472.818168] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[ 1472.818170] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[ 1472.818182] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-17-16-1.sfi
[ 1472.820322] OOM killer enabled.
[ 1472.820324] Restarting tasks ... done.
[ 1472.854208] thermal thermal_zone6: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[ 1472.877302] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: PCI bridge to [bus 02-3a]
[ 1472.877305] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:   bridge window [io  0x4000-0x5fff]
[ 1472.877308] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:   bridge window [mem 0xc0000000-0xd60fffff]
[ 1472.877310] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:   bridge window [mem 0x80000000-0xa1ffffff 64bit pref]
[ 1472.983171] PM: suspend exit
[ 1473.222701] rfkill: input handler disabled
[ 1473.303430] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Down
[ 1473.688309] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
[ 1474.214211] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[ 1474.214885] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1366450 usecs
[ 1474.214952] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[ 1474.227984] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 12786 usecs
[ 1474.227990] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-17-16-1.ddc
[ 1474.235035] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[ 1476.581191] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 94:10:3e:e4:01:96
[ 1476.583340] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 94:10:3e:e4:01:96 (try 1/3)
[ 1476.622092] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[ 1476.624795] wlp0s20f3: associate with 94:10:3e:e4:01:96 (try 1/3)
[ 1476.626157] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 94:10:3e:e4:01:96 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[ 1476.629089] wlp0s20f3: associated
[ 1476.640478] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp0s20f3: link becomes ready
```

`cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep enabled` shows:

```
GLAN      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1f.6
XHC   S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
RP01      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.0
RP05      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.4
PXSX      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:02:00.0
RP09      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
RP13      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.4
SLPB      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0E:00
LID   S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
```

I disabled everything by `echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup`.

What other reason can it be? I've tried all on I can find on the Internet.  I've also tried  Ubuntu 16.04 and Fedora 30, yet get the same problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated!! I don't want to install windows...

Comment: Update: it turns out that it *might* not be an Ubuntu issue. I put the original m.2 SSD drive with Windows 10 back to the machine and encounter the same issue! Even worse, it boots up immediately after being shut down! I did BIOS diagnostics per suggestions from Lenovo's technicians, but it passes every test. So I still don't know what the problem is. Now I'm returning this laptop to them and waiting for a replacement. Will try Ubuntu on the replacement machine after I got it.

Comment: FINAL UPDATE: it was a hardware isse. Now I got a replacement thinkpad, everything works out fine.