# Wifi connects to all but one network after 19.10 update

Tags: networking, wireless, thinkpad, iwlwifi, 19.10

*Edit: Solved in comments via @libnull-dev. Changing router security settings addressed the issue. Also, thanks to @libnull-dev I learned that despite Pop_OS! being built on Ubuntu, the best place to log related issues is in the [Pos_OS! github issue tracker](https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues).*

*Edit 2: also found a great [Wireless info script](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/1013974) to help provide better information for diagnosing wireless issues. From the comment:*

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info
```

---

I'm stuck in my troubleshooting process and I need help debugging.

Running **Pop_OS! 19.10** on a **Lenovo Thinkpad x1 Extreme**. It does not connect to my home network. I updated my desktop to Ubuntu 19.10 and it connects great. The laptop dual boots with Windows 10, and it can connect as well. Nothing changed with the router, though I did factory reset it to be safe with no luck.

The only variable between when the laptop connected and did not was 19.04 -> 19.10

TL;DR of my logs below include

- `journalctl -b | grep wifi`
- `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`
- `dmesg | grep -e wl -e iwl`
- `lshw -C network`
- `cat /var/log/syslog | grep iwlwifi`
- `systemctl status network-manager` of both failed and successful connections (home network and iPhone tether, respectively)

If there's any other info I should include, I'm happy to.

One error I'm aware of is the `BIOS contains WGDS but not WRDS`. I believe this was an issue preventing the computer from fully suspending and was solved by [toggling XHC in wakeup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987755/suspend-not-working-help-needed-to-debug), though I still see the message in the syslog.

### journalctl -b | grep wifi

```
Nov 01 02:00:40 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <info>  [1572595240.8799] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) access point 'My iPhone' has security, but secrets are required.
Nov 01 02:00:40 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <info>  [1572595240.8848] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'My iPhone' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Nov 01 02:00:41 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <info>  [1572595241.1732] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "My iPhone"
Nov 01 08:01:58 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <info>  [1572616918.9249] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) access point 'HOME_WIFI_5G' has security, but secrets are required.
Nov 01 08:01:58 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <info>  [1572616918.9309] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'HOME_WIFI_5G' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Nov 01 08:02:01 pop-os kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov 01 08:02:01 pop-os kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov 01 08:02:02 pop-os kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov 01 08:02:02 pop-os kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov 01 08:02:04 pop-os kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov 01 08:02:04 pop-os kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov 01 08:02:04 pop-os kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov 01 08:02:08 pop-os dbus-daemon[1242]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.983' (uid=1000 pid=8116 comm="gnome-control-center wifi " label="unconfined")
Nov 01 08:02:18 pop-os kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov 01 08:02:19 pop-os kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov 01 08:02:19 pop-os kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov 01 08:02:19 pop-os kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov 01 08:02:24 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <warn>  [1572616944.1937] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Nov 01 08:02:24 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <warn>  [1572616944.1965] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Nov 01 08:02:31 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <info>  [1572616951.1907] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'HOME_WIFI_5G' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Nov 01 08:02:44 pop-os kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov 01 08:02:45 pop-os kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov 01 08:02:45 pop-os kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov 01 08:02:45 pop-os kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov 01 08:02:56 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <warn>  [1572616976.1929] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Nov 01 08:02:56 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <warn>  [1572616976.1954] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Nov 01 08:02:58 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <info>  [1572616978.7874] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) access point 'My iPhone' has security, but secrets are required.
Nov 01 08:02:58 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <info>  [1572616978.7996] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'My iPhone' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Nov 01 08:02:58 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <info>  [1572616978.9590] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "My iPhone"
Nov 01 08:03:02 pop-os dbus-daemon[1242]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.983' (uid=1000 pid=8116 comm="gnome-control-center wifi " label="unconfined")
Nov 01 08:03:40 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <info>  [1572617020.0538] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) access point 'HOME_WIFI_5G, too' has security, but secrets are required.
Nov 01 08:03:44 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <info>  [1572617024.7577] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'HOME_WIFI_5G, too' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Nov 01 08:04:10 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <warn>  [1572617050.1930] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Nov 01 08:04:10 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <warn>  [1572617050.1965] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Nov 01 08:04:16 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <info>  [1572617056.3711] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) access point 'My iPhone' has security, but secrets are required.
Nov 01 08:04:16 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <info>  [1572617056.3765] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'My iPhone' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Nov 01 08:04:24 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <info>  [1572617064.0736] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) access point 'My iPhone' has security, but secrets are required.
Nov 01 08:04:24 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <info>  [1572617064.0827] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'My iPhone' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Nov 01 08:04:27 pop-os NetworkManager[1262]: <info>  [1572617067.4427] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "My iPhone"
```

### lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

```
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] [8086:0030]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

### dmesg | grep -e wl -e iwl

```
[  221.940192] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from bc:99:11:53:76:36 by local choice (Reason: 1=UNSPECIFIED)
[  224.394062] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with bc:99:11:53:76:36
[  224.400605] wlp0s20f3: send auth to bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 1/3)
[  224.439626] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  224.441378] wlp0s20f3: associate with bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 1/3)
[  224.442290] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from bc:99:11:53:76:36 (capab=0x11 status=30 aid=1)
[  224.442302] wlp0s20f3: bc:99:11:53:76:36 rejected association temporarily; comeback duration 196 TU (200 ms)
[  224.442426] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[  224.641732] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[  224.645482] wlp0s20f3: associate with bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 2/3)
[  224.649181] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from bc:99:11:53:76:36 (capab=0x11 status=30 aid=1)
[  224.649190] wlp0s20f3: bc:99:11:53:76:36 rejected association temporarily; comeback duration 196 TU (200 ms)
[  224.841714] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[  224.853459] wlp0s20f3: associate with bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 3/3)
[  224.855481] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from bc:99:11:53:76:36 (capab=0x11 status=30 aid=1)
[  224.855491] wlp0s20f3: bc:99:11:53:76:36 rejected association temporarily; comeback duration 196 TU (200 ms)
[  225.041695] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[  225.057495] wlp0s20f3: association with bc:99:11:53:76:36 timed out
[  227.105813] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with bc:99:11:53:76:36
[  227.113132] wlp0s20f3: send auth to bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 1/3)
[  227.152176] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  227.153662] wlp0s20f3: associate with bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 1/3)
[  227.154598] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from bc:99:11:53:76:36 (capab=0x11 status=30 aid=1)
[  227.154607] wlp0s20f3: bc:99:11:53:76:36 rejected association temporarily; comeback duration 196 TU (200 ms)
[  227.241274] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[  227.361710] wlp0s20f3: associate with bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 2/3)
[  227.365889] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from bc:99:11:53:76:36 (capab=0x11 status=30 aid=1)
[  227.365899] wlp0s20f3: bc:99:11:53:76:36 rejected association temporarily; comeback duration 196 TU (200 ms)
[  227.441158] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[  227.569679] wlp0s20f3: associate with bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 3/3)
[  227.571328] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from bc:99:11:53:76:36 (capab=0x11 status=30 aid=1)
[  227.571330] wlp0s20f3: bc:99:11:53:76:36 rejected association temporarily; comeback duration 196 TU (200 ms)
[  227.641058] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[  227.776525] wlp0s20f3: association with bc:99:11:53:76:36 timed out
[  230.102006] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with bc:99:11:53:76:36
[  230.109369] wlp0s20f3: send auth to bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 1/3)
[  230.153104] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  230.157881] wlp0s20f3: associate with bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 1/3)
[  230.158952] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from bc:99:11:53:76:36 (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=1)
[  230.160180] wlp0s20f3: associated
[  230.172304] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from bc:99:11:53:76:36 by local choice (Reason: 1=UNSPECIFIED)
[  241.705657] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with bc:99:11:53:76:36
[  241.712239] wlp0s20f3: send auth to bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 1/3)
[  241.751300] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  241.754459] wlp0s20f3: associate with bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 1/3)
[  241.755306] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from bc:99:11:53:76:36 (capab=0x11 status=30 aid=1)
[  241.755310] wlp0s20f3: bc:99:11:53:76:36 rejected association temporarily; comeback duration 196 TU (200 ms)
[  241.755478] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[  241.955114] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[  241.962493] wlp0s20f3: associate with bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 2/3)
[  241.966319] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from bc:99:11:53:76:36 (capab=0x11 status=30 aid=1)
[  241.966323] wlp0s20f3: bc:99:11:53:76:36 rejected association temporarily; comeback duration 196 TU (200 ms)
[  242.154975] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[  242.166547] wlp0s20f3: associate with bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 3/3)
[  242.168206] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from bc:99:11:53:76:36 (capab=0x11 status=30 aid=1)
[  242.168216] wlp0s20f3: bc:99:11:53:76:36 rejected association temporarily; comeback duration 196 TU (200 ms)
[  242.355052] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[  242.370556] wlp0s20f3: association with bc:99:11:53:76:36 timed out
[  256.365884] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with bc:99:11:53:76:36
[  256.373288] wlp0s20f3: send auth to bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 1/3)
[  256.412393] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  256.418812] wlp0s20f3: associate with bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 1/3)
[  256.419872] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from bc:99:11:53:76:36 (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=1)
[  256.421215] wlp0s20f3: associated
[  256.432102] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from bc:99:11:53:76:36 by local choice (Reason: 1=UNSPECIFIED)
[  267.774755] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with bc:99:11:53:76:36
[  267.782056] wlp0s20f3: send auth to bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 1/3)
[  267.821001] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  267.822885] wlp0s20f3: associate with bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 1/3)
[  267.823807] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from bc:99:11:53:76:36 (capab=0x11 status=30 aid=1)
[  267.823818] wlp0s20f3: bc:99:11:53:76:36 rejected association temporarily; comeback duration 196 TU (200 ms)
[  267.823895] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[  268.023265] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[  268.026959] wlp0s20f3: associate with bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 2/3)
[  268.030638] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from bc:99:11:53:76:36 (capab=0x11 status=30 aid=1)
[  268.030647] wlp0s20f3: bc:99:11:53:76:36 rejected association temporarily; comeback duration 196 TU (200 ms)
[  268.223658] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[  268.230879] wlp0s20f3: associate with bc:99:11:53:76:36 (try 3/3)
[  268.232511] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from bc:99:11:53:76:36 (capab=0x11 status=30 aid=1)
[  268.232514] wlp0s20f3: bc:99:11:53:76:36 rejected association temporarily; comeback duration 196 TU (200 ms)
[  268.423332] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[  268.434967] wlp0s20f3: association with bc:99:11:53:76:36 timed out
[  281.684608] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 76:2f:75:13:b6:08
[  281.690243] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 76:2f:75:13:b6:08 (try 1/3)
[  281.729949] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  281.730949] wlp0s20f3: associate with 76:2f:75:13:b6:08 (try 1/3)
[  281.737833] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 76:2f:75:13:b6:08 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[  281.740176] wlp0s20f3: associated
[  281.782115] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp0s20f3: link becomes ready
[  282.029965] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 76:2f:75:13:b6:08
[  322.850790] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 76:2f:75:13:b6:08 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  327.619115] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with bc:99:11:53:76:35
[  327.625421] wlp0s20f3: send auth to bc:99:11:53:76:35 (try 1/3)
[  327.627624] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  327.633890] wlp0s20f3: associate with bc:99:11:53:76:35 (try 1/3)
[  327.637822] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from bc:99:11:53:76:35 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[  327.640339] wlp0s20f3: associated
[  327.668924] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from bc:99:11:53:76:35 by local choice (Reason: 1=UNSPECIFIED)
[  330.098823] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with bc:99:11:53:76:35
[  330.105212] wlp0s20f3: send auth to bc:99:11:53:76:35 (try 1/3)
[  330.107723] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  330.109195] wlp0s20f3: associate with bc:99:11:53:76:35 (try 1/3)
[  330.113181] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from bc:99:11:53:76:35 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[  330.115582] wlp0s20f3: associated
[  330.130225] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from bc:99:11:53:76:35 by local choice (Reason: 1=UNSPECIFIED)
[  332.551059] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with bc:99:11:53:76:35
[  332.557551] wlp0s20f3: send auth to bc:99:11:53:76:35 (try 1/3)
[  332.564070] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  332.565074] wlp0s20f3: associate with bc:99:11:53:76:35 (try 1/3)
[  332.570493] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from bc:99:11:53:76:35 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[  332.574898] wlp0s20f3: associated
[  332.585569] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from bc:99:11:53:76:35 by local choice (Reason: 1=UNSPECIFIED)
[  333.976596] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with bc:99:11:53:76:35
[  333.982954] wlp0s20f3: send auth to bc:99:11:53:76:35 (try 1/3)
[  333.985500] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  333.992181] wlp0s20f3: associate with bc:99:11:53:76:35 (try 1/3)
[  333.996611] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from bc:99:11:53:76:35 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[  333.999071] wlp0s20f3: associated
[  334.019769] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from bc:99:11:53:76:35 by local choice (Reason: 1=UNSPECIFIED)
[  345.896991] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with bc:99:11:53:76:35
[  345.903314] wlp0s20f3: send auth to bc:99:11:53:76:35 (try 1/3)
[  345.905680] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  345.909206] wlp0s20f3: associate with bc:99:11:53:76:35 (try 1/3)
[  345.913118] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from bc:99:11:53:76:35 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[  345.917340] wlp0s20f3: associated
[  345.933173] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from bc:99:11:53:76:35 by local choice (Reason: 1=UNSPECIFIED)
```

### lshw -C network

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network:0               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 10
       serial: 48:f1:7f:90:9b:ba
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-20-generic firmware=46.6bf1df06.0 ip=172.20.10.11 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes
       resources: iomemory:400-3ff irq:16 memory:404b10c000-404b10ffff
```

### cat /var/log/syslog | grep iwlwifi

*Full output had many redundant entries. This was shortened*

```
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.421752] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.421753] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8042:654c426c
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.499884] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.543884] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.545396] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.545398] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.545739] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.631681] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x318
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.639254] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.639664] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.683805] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 48:f1:7f:90:9b:ba
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.785551] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
Nov  8 08:41:39 pop-os NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1573227699.0923] rfkill2: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill2) (driver iwlwifi)
Nov  8 08:41:39 pop-os kernel: [    6.205475] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
Nov  8 08:41:39 pop-os kernel: [    6.319091] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
Nov  8 08:41:39 pop-os kernel: [    6.384077] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
Nov  8 08:41:39 pop-os kernel: [    6.390968] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.495765] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.495766] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8042:654c426c
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.547883] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.553422] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.555005] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.555007] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.555275] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.577279] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x318
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.586254] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.586683] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.629359] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 48:f1:7f:90:9b:ba
Nov  8 08:41:38 pop-os kernel: [    4.844004] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
Nov  8 08:41:39 pop-os NetworkManager[1300]: <info>  [1573227699.0991] rfkill2: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill2) (driver iwlwifi)
Nov  8 08:41:39 pop-os kernel: [    6.410486] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
Nov  8 08:41:39 pop-os kernel: [    6.526716] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
Nov  8 08:41:39 pop-os kernel: [    6.591726] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
Nov  8 08:41:39 pop-os kernel: [    6.598532] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
Nov  8 08:42:33 pop-os kernel: [   60.834476] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov  8 08:42:34 pop-os kernel: [   61.033970] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov  8 08:42:34 pop-os kernel: [   61.235438] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov  8 08:42:34 pop-os kernel: [   61.434286] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov  8 08:42:36 pop-os kernel: [   63.635410] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov  8 08:42:36 pop-os kernel: [   63.835459] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov  8 08:42:37 pop-os kernel: [   64.035532] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov  8 08:44:09 pop-os kernel: [  156.022463] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Nov  8 08:44:09 pop-os kernel: [  156.222310] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
```

### systemctl status network-manager

*This is after failed connection to wifi*

```
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-11-08 10:23:20 MST; 1h 35min ago
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
 Main PID: 1200 (NetworkManager)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 18.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           └─1200 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Nov 08 11:54:33 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <warn>  [1573239273.9736] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Nov 08 11:54:34 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1573239274.3509] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
Nov 08 11:54:34 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1573239274.3509] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> inactive
Nov 08 11:54:36 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <warn>  [1573239276.0906] device (wlp0s20f3): no secrets: User canceled the secrets request.
Nov 08 11:54:36 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1573239276.0906] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 08 11:54:36 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1573239276.0911] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Nov 08 11:54:36 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <warn>  [1573239276.0924] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: failed for connection 'HOME_WIFI_5G'
Nov 08 11:54:36 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1573239276.0929] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 08 11:55:40 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1573239340.9865] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Nov 08 11:55:40 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1573239340.9866] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> scanning
```

*This is a successful tether to my iPhone*

```
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-11-08 10:23:20 MST; 1h 37min ago
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
 Main PID: 1200 (NetworkManager)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 18.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           └─1200 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Nov 08 12:00:59 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1573239659.0838] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 08 12:00:59 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1573239659.0843] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 08 12:00:59 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1573239659.0852] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Nov 08 12:00:59 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1573239659.0913] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Nov 08 12:00:59 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1573239659.0917] policy: set 'My iPhone' (wlp0s20f3) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Nov 08 12:00:59 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1573239659.0971] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: successful, device activated.
Nov 08 12:00:59 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1573239659.5078] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Nov 08 12:01:00 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1573239660.6043] dhcp6 (wlp0s20f3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Nov 08 12:01:00 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1573239660.6075] policy: set 'My iPhone' (wlp0s20f3) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Nov 08 12:01:00 pop-os NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1573239660.6154] dhcp6 (wlp0s20f3): state changed unknown -> bound
```

Comment: So if this issue only exists in POP OS 19.10, why are you asking here?  This is for Ubuntu issues

Comment: as this question is on hold, I can't create an answer here, btw, I am not sure about being it out of topic as this is related to `backport-iwlwifi-dkms 8042-0ubuntu1` package. Moderators should be more knowledgeable. Any way, it seems that if in your router wifi settings you have `TKIP and AES` enabled, the solution is either downgrade  `backport-iwlwifi-dkms 8042-0ubuntu1` to [7906-0ubuntu1](https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/738) or simply change settings in your route for passphraset to `AES` only and reboot your router. This worked for me having exactly the same issue.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if this is in the wrong place. Several reasons I asked here. 1. Pop is 99% Ubuntu. 2. I need help troubleshooting, so if there's a better place for me to ask, that would help me troubleshoot. I'll look into Unix&Linux. 3. I remember seeing a related bug in my searching, though sadly I can't find the exact link now. It was similar to [this error on launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/backport-iwlwifi-dkms/+bug/1849891)

Comment: @libnull-dev Oh my gosh that `AES` setting worked for me. Thank you! I love/hate when a multi-day problem is solved by the simplest means.